# Front-End Framework that serves static files that use AJAX for dynamic content

Tags: library

I'm looking for a variation of the many JavaScript framework libraries (Vue, Svelte, etc...) that is not a single page, and where view templates are interpreted/written to static pages, where each page, individually, uses AJAX calls to an API to populate the content on that page.

That is, a framework where the dynamic template substitutions are rendered on the client side, but not a situation where the client downloads the entire app upfront (the client would still download each page individually). That is, from the client perspective, a static page is downloaded (which is an empty template plus JavaScript), the JS on that page runs an AJAX call to an API, and then it uses the response from the API to fill in the template.  (Rather than the template substitutions being made on the server side)  A link to another page on the site would GET a different static file of the same sort.

Is there an existing framework library that operates this way, and which is it?

Comment: Could you please explain why you would like it this way.

Comment: I feel like all the pedantic SO hall-monitors I had to go through to finally post my question in a place where it it won't be closed for [insert your pedantic reason here], would say that my reason for wanting it this way is off-topic and such discussions belong elsewhere.

Comment: But, I'll bite anyways, cause Forget those guys:  1)  The processing power used to do the template substitutions would come from the client side and reduce load on the server  2)  The structure would be intuitive.